# PHP Warning: Cannot load module "http" because required module "raphf" is not loaded in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu

When entering artisan commands in laravel- ubuntu 20.04
it shows following error

**PHP Warning:  Cannot load module "http" because required module "raphf" is not loaded in Unknown on line 0**

PHP version 8.1.1,
Laravel 8 ,
Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is related to your php version

You may installed all the packages like **raphf** in another php version and you are using php version 8.1.1

Solution :-  Reinstall all the packages with your current php version

Then Run :-

sudo service apache2 restart

sudo update-alternatives --config php

sudo update-alternatives --config phar

sudo update-alternatives --config phar.phar

sudo service apache2 restart